# How to enforce a 1 or 2 line title in AlertDialog on Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I'm running into problems with AlertDialog having titles that span more than 3 lines.  Ideally I'd like a title to be truncated with ellipsis if it is longer than 2 lines. I have no control over the content/length of titles - they represent document names and quite often are longer than AlertDialog can handle.

Currently I see that AlertDialog truncates titles but does not do it gracefully:

- does not add ellipsis when truncation takes place
- the height of the content view of the dialog (between title and buttons) does not seem to be calculated properly - bottom of the content view is cut off.

This is why I'd rather display only a single line with ellipsis if possible.  A 2-line title with ellipsis would be even better as long as it does not cut off the content view.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to deal with the above.
Thanks.

Comment: Might invest in creating your own Dialog?

Comment: you should create a custom Dialog by yourself..